# Why does macro hygiene not prevent collisions between multiple const definitions?

Tags: macros, rust, metaprogramming, hygiene

I thought "hygiene" would prevent collisions between `X`s defined within my macro `m!` but that turned out not to be the case.  What am I misunderstanding?

```
macro_rules! m {
    ($e:expr) => {
        const X: i32 = $e;
    };
}

m!(0);
m!(1);

fn main() {
    m!(2);
    m!(3);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fe02c9f349fea876d79db29b64a60c5a)

Error message:

```
error[E0428]: the name `X` is defined multiple times
 --> src/main.rs:3:9
  |
3 |         const X: i32 = $e;
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |         |
  |         `X` redefined here
  |         previous definition of the value `X` here
...
7 | m!(0);
  | ------ in this macro invocation
  |
  = note: `X` must be defined only once in the value namespace of this module
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From *The Rust Programming Language* (first edition)'s [section on macro hygiene](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.30.0/book/first-edition/macros.html#hygiene):

> This [i.e. renaming] holds for `let` bindings and loop labels, but not for items

The Rust reference defines [items](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items.html):

> An *item* is a component of a crate. Items are organized within a crate
>   by a nested set of modules. Every crate has a single "outermost"
>   anonymous module; all further items within the crate have paths within
>   the module tree of the crate.
>
> Items are entirely determined at compile-time, generally remain fixed
>   during execution, and may reside in read-only memory.
>
> There are several kinds of items:
>
> - modules
> - `extern crate` declarations
> - `use` declarations
> - function definitions
> - type definitions
> - struct definitions
> - enumeration definitions
> - union definitions
> - **constant items**
> - static items
> - trait definitions
> - implementations
> - `extern` blocks

This makes sense: if you you introduce an item in a macro you presumably want to actually use it from other items/modules/crates (and thus outside the macro), but you can't if you don't know its name, so the compiler can't rename it.

Comment: Thanks. So it's by design. "if you you introduce an item in a macro you presumably want to actually use it," Well, I guess that's not how we are supposed to use what's advertised as a hygienic macro system...

Comment: @nodakai Sorry, I missed "outside the macro" there. In your case, if you put `println!("X = {}", X);` after the last `m!(3)`, what do you expect it to print?

Comment: I'd expect a "unknown variable X" error when I heard Rust macros were hygienic.

Comment: And that _is_ what you'd get for a variable (`let` binding), but `const` doesn't introduce one.